# Update handsontable by editing table and/or eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am using the `rhandsontable` package in a Shiny app which should have the following functionality:

- the data used in the calculation can be randomly generated, invoked by an `actionButton` (and when the app starts)
- the data can be manually edited by the user via the handsontable object
- after manual editing it should be possible to re-generate random data, invoking a new calculation

The following app does exactly that what I want, but I could not figure it out how to get rid of the global variable `did_recalc`. It is a minimal example, where the data consists of two numeric values which are summed up.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

did_recalc <- FALSE

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  textOutput('result'),
  actionButton("recalc", "generate new random vals and calculate")
)

server <- function(input,output,session)({

  dataset_generator <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    df <- as.data.frame(runif(2))
    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df)})
    did_recalc <<- TRUE
    df
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$result <- renderText({ 
    df <- dataset_generator()
    if (!is.null(input$table) && !did_recalc) 
      df <- hot_to_r(input$table)
    did_recalc <<- FALSE
    sum(df)
  })
}) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I remove the `!did_recalc` condition within `output$result <- ...` then editing the table still invokes a (correct) calculation. But if "recalc" is pressed (after some manual editing was done), then the "recalc" button just generates new random values, but without recalculating the sum.

It seems to me, that `input$table` can just be changed by manual edits of the table object and does not care about new values given via `renderRHandsontable`. Hence I need this hack with the global variable, which allows me to track if the user just re-generated the data (causing that `input$table` is "outdated")

Has anybody an idea how to get the functionality of this example without the global variable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could store the data in a `reactiveValues` and have two observers updating it; one if the button is clicked, one if the table is edited by hand.

In your `output$table` and `output$result`, you then just need to use the data that is in the `reactiveValues`. Here's an example (same `ui.R` as you posted):

```
server <- function(input,output,session)({
  values <- reactiveValues(data=as.data.frame(runif(2)))

  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data <- as.data.frame(runif(2))
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
     values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
  })


  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data)
    })


  output$result <- renderText({ 
    sum(values$data)
  })
})
```

Comment: This is a very helpful example ... I'm wondering how I might be able to replace the hard coded `runif(2)` with a result from another UI element.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722757/update-handsontable-by-editing-table-and-or-eventreactive#33739317