# R Shiny: Store reactive expression to avoid recursion

Tags: r, recursion, shiny

I'm having a problem with recursion in my shiny app. Suppose my app reads a file and creates a dataset (`dataset()`). Then I have a function that processes the said dataset, creating another one (`dataset.proc()`). I can apply processing to the dataset as many times as I want (there are several processing methods). Another function keeps track of what's the latest dataset created (`dataset.current()`).

Here´s a simple example of the important part of my server.R script:

```
dataset <- reactive(#reads file and creates dataset)

dataset.current <- reactive ({
  if (!is.null(dataset())){
    if (!is.null(dataset.proc())) {
      return(dataset.proc())
    } else {
      return (dataset())
    }
  }
}) 

dataset.proc <- reactive(#processes dataset.current() according to user input, creates a processed dataset)
```

Is there any way I can 'store' dataset.proc() as a non-reactive expression to avoid the obvious error:

> evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Perhaps you could store `dataset` as a reactive value (see: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html). When changing a reactive value (i.e. loading a new data set), all other reactive functions depending on it, are triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser :) I finally solved the problem adapting the idea from the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'normal' R variables in the server code. For example,

```
current <- dataset() # Load initial dataset

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$dataset.current <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(dataset.proc())
  })

  dataset.proc <- reactive({
    # Instead of dataset.current(), use the current variable

    # Processing ... 

    current <- data.frame("Processed")
    return(current)
  })
})
```

Before returning the result of the dataset.proc reactive expression, 'save' the result of the processing in the `current` variable. Next time, the dataset.proc expression can start from the value in `current`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The problem is I need `dataset.current()` in the code, to tell me which dataset is the latest created, because there are other parts of my app that need to work with the last dataset and rely on `dataset.current()`.

Comment: I just solved the problem adapting your idea. I set `current`as a global variable and then, inside de server, made it 'look' reactive to shiny so other functions could see when it changed its value with `makeReactiveBinding('current')`. Hope it helps other people too.

Comment: Usually global variables could (and should) be avoided. With the answer to this question (which I did ask) I could get rid of a global variable in my Shiny app, which is a somehow similar problem (updating a data set and triggering a calculation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722757/update-handsontable-by-editing-table-and-or-eventreactive

Comment: True. A reactiveValue is indeed the betetr solution.