# Load, edit, and download a csv file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, yui-datatable

I am trying to load a csv file to a shiny program, edit it in place and download the edited file. I found that the package `DT` provides some functionalities for the same. I modified the [example here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html) to read csv from the file and [example here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/) to write the output. I was also trying to edit the loaded CSV in place using the DT's experimental features [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28). My code below loads csv, and saves the CSV but while trying to edit it in place it crashes with the error:

```
Warning: Error in <<-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
Stack trace (innermost first):
65: observeEventHandler [/home/user/ShinyApp/EditingValues/server.R#40]
```

Basically, my problem I believe I am not able to provide values to x from the read csv in the [example here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28).

My `ui.R` is

```
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"'),
      tags$hr(),
      p('Once you are done download the  data'),
      downloadButton('x3', 'Download Data')
    ),
    mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('x1')
    )
  )
)
```

My `server.R` is

```
# By default, the file size limit is 5MB. It can be changed by
# setting this option. Here we'll raise limit to 9MB.

# Install DT, experimental version may not work well 
# devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT@feature/editor')

library(shiny) # The main program
library(DT) # Edit the output
library(data.table) # Faster read and write

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

function(input, output, session) {
   dataframe<-reactive({
        if (is.null(input$file1))
            return(NULL)  
       dta_types = fread(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header,
                         sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote, nrows = 0,
                         strip.white = TRUE, data.table = FALSE)
        data<-fread(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header,
                    sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses= rep("character", ncol(dta_types)))
        data
    })

  output$x3 = downloadHandler('mtcars-filtered.csv', content = function(file) {
      s = input$x1_rows_all
      write.csv(dataframe()[s, , drop = FALSE], file)
  })
  output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(dataframe(), selection = 'none')

  proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      dataframe()[i, j] <<- DT:::coerceValue(v, dataframe()[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, dataframe(), resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
}
```

How can this be achieved? I am sure I missing simple assignment somewhere. I tried

```
x=dataframe()
```

before

output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(dataframe(), selection = 'none')

and using x instead of dataframe() everywhere but that crashes the app before it is loaded. Thanks for the inputs.
A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722757/update-handsontable-by-editing-table-and-or-eventreactive) question using `rhandsontable` also does not have an answer yet.

Comment: Using `rhandsontable` is quite easy. You just need to use `hot_to_r` function to convert the user-edited table back to R object and then save it.