# Shiny - Editing rhandsontable tables with multiple input and output elements

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I've been working with this post as a starting point.
[Update handsontable by editing table and/or eventReactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722757/update-handsontable-by-editing-table-and-or-eventreactive#33739317)

Very helpful, but I'm trying to extend it to specify the number of values in the table, then update a plot based on the table values after editing.

Here's what I have so far.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(colorSpec)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "number of values", 2),
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  textOutput('result'),
  plotOutput('plot'),
  actionButton("recalc", "generate new random vals and calculate")
)


server <- function(input,output,session)({
  values <- reactiveValues(data=as.data.frame(runif(input$x)))

  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data <- as.data.frame(runif(input$x))
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
      values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
  })


  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data)
  })


  output$result <- renderText({
    sum(values$data)
  })

  output$plot <- reactivePlot({
    barplot(values$data)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get an error on the `reactiveValues` line because I'm trying to use `input$x`.  The previous post had a hard coded value of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were almost there. You can, however, not use an input for creating a reactive value. But this is anyways not eneded and you can initiate it with a `NULL`.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "number of values", 2),
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  textOutput('result'),
  plotOutput('plot'),
  actionButton("recalc", "generate new random vals and calculate")
)


server <- function(input,output,session)({
  values <- reactiveValues(data = NULL) ## assign it with NULL

  ## button press resets now the data frame
  observeEvent(input$recalc, { 
    values$data$x <- 0
  })

  ## changes in numericInput sets all (!) new values
  observe({
    req(input$x)
    values$data <- data.frame(x = runif(input$x))
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
      values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
  })


  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    req(values$data)
    rhandsontable(values$data)
  })


  output$result <- renderText({
    req(values$data)
    sum(values$data)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(values$data)
    barplot(values$data$x)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is close ... is there a way to add the additional random value as the number in the `numericInput` is increased?  My example actually doesn't perfectly match my real world situation.  I would like to have the `actionbutton` set all values to `0` so I think separating the addition of the new value and calculation of the new sum from the button action is necessary.

Comment: Changed my code. but i am not sure what you want to achieve? I assume now that teh button, sets everything to `0` while changes in `numericInput` creates a set of new random variables

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain clearly but you're example seems to be doing exactly what I was looking for!!  Let me do a little more testing but this is clearly on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reactive()` instead of `reactiveValues` to do this:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(colorSpec)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "number of values", 2),
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),
  textOutput('result')
)


server <- function(input,output,session)({

  values <- reactive({
    foo <- as.data.frame(runif(input$x))
    colnames(foo) <- c("Col1")
    return(foo)
  })

  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values())
  })


  output$result <- renderText({
    sum(values())
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This appears to handle the `numericInput` portion but directly editing of the table doesn't seem to work anymore.  Plot function is also not included.

Comment: To be clear, the part that doesn't work anymore is that when the table is edited the `output$result` doesn't update anymore.  Just trying to figure out how to link all the pieces.  Thanks

Comment: Understood. Will try resolving.

Comment: Any additional thoughts?